# how to use next() to find the closest ul in jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle

i have a simple menu, something like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="m_li">
         <div><span>+</span><a href="#" >myself</a></div>
        <ul class="test" id="x_ul">
            <li id="li">
                <a href="#" >Pictures</a>
            </li>
            <li id="li">
                <a href="#" >Audio</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="profile_modeling_li">
        <div><span>+</span><a href="#" >friend</a></div>
        <ul class="test" id="y_ul">
            <li id="li">
                <a href="#" >Pictures</a>
            </li>
            <li id="li">
                <a href="#" >Video</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then i use jquery so when i click on the `+` sign the ul slides down:

```
$("#navigation > li > div > span").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(300);
});
```

the issue is that `$(this).next('ul')` doesn't seem to fond the next ul

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You could use `$(this).find('ul')`

Comment: No, you can't.`find` looks into the elements descendants while in this case, the `ul` is the sibling of the element's parent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
$(this).parent().next()
```

instead of

```
$(this).next();
```

and, of course, you can pass a selector (more simple or more complex) that identifies the desired element as argument:

```
$(this).parent().next('ul.test[id$="_ul]"');
```

Answer (score 3):

`.next / .prev` traverse through siblings and ul is not a children of the span. You should probably find closest `li` and find `.test`.

```
 $(this).closest('li').find('ul.test')
```

Comment: `.next()` and `.prev()` traverse through **siblings**, not children.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist aaw.. i meant siblings but wrote as children. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Convert

```
$(this).next('ul')
```

to

```
$(this).parent().next('ul')
```

You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/PYqS2/